# CURL get two html pages in PHP

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I am getting contents from a website via CURL in PHP(simple html dom).

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo str_get_html($output);
```

It give me this html on top and then rest of the page html

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>  <h2>Object moved to <a href="/LocationSelection.aspx">here</a>.</h2>  </body></html>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN".........
```

I do not want to get first html.I want to get html only starting from `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"`

How can i do it with CURL?Is there any other approach?

EDIT: Can we make any delay in CURL,so that whole html load via ajax first and then.Like we are using **sleep(10)**

Comment: you need to get correct URL

Comment: URL is correct but first it find location and then redirect automatically...when i run url in browser it work fine

Comment: Why do you need this? What problem are you trying to solve by this?

Comment: The browser follows the redirect. So in curl use the url that the browser got redirected to.

Comment: sir the URL is not correct, when you are running it into browser 301 redirect is transparent to you , whereas in curl the response is verbose

Comment: Here is url https://novocinemas.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to recover the second HTML, so just add this to `curl` options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Then you will recover `Locations.aspx` without the `Object moved.....`

Answer (score 0):

Your request :

```
novocinemas.com/Home.aspx
```

I just ran it in Chrome and got a 302 status and then the redirect happend:

```
Home.aspx   GET 302 text/html   Other   260 B   1.25 s  
LocationSelection.aspx  GET 200 text/html   http://novocinemas.com/Home.aspx    2.2 KB  705 ms
```

Thanks
Satyadeep

Comment: sir as I told , there is a redirect happening and this is evident from the log

Comment: so what is the solution?Is there any other way to get its contents?

Comment: hit LocationSelection.aspx also please accept the answer if this helped

Answer (score 0):

After you receive output from CURL, how about if you replace the first html with empty string using code below.

```
$pattern = '/<html>.*<\/html>/i';
$replace = preg_replace($pattern, '', $outputFromCurl);

echo htmlentities($replace);
```

Then you will get the second html

Hope it helps